# How do I get an array of id's having a specific value as their latest value at a given time in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with the following data:

```
    SELECT DATE("2019-11-11") as date, "old" as state, 1 as id UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATE("2019-11-12"), "new", 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATE("2019-11-13"), "new" , 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATE("2019-11-14"), "old" , 1
```

I want to get all id's in the "new" state for each day - the state should be preserved until told otherwise (switched to "old" in this case). How do I do this? I have tried working with ARRAY_AGG but cannot come up with a solution where I could both look at the latest value for the id as well as check for the new state.

So with the example above I would like the output to be:

```
date      | new_state_ids

2019-11-11| NULL
2019-11-12| [1]
2019-11-13| [1,2]
2019-11-14| [2]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select date, state, id, 
  case state when 'new' then 
      array_agg(id) over(partition by grp order by date) 
    else if(prev_id is null, null, [prev_id])
  end new_state_ids
from (
  select *, countif(new_grp) over(order by date) grp
  from (
    select *, 
      state != lag(state) over(order by date) new_grp,
      lag(id) over(order by date) prev_id
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.

While your solution works with the provided sample table, it breaks if e.g. id 1 and 2 "new" state events are swapped as your solution is only looking at the prior row for the replacement value when changing state. Adding a 3rd id or further changing the state for id 2 would also cause breaking.

Please see the original question for a dataset that demonstrates this behavior, I have also added the desired output for the new dataset.

Comment: i don't see any new example in your question

Comment: example added, sorry didn't expect such a quick response

Comment: in some cases - the answer can be only as good as the question is. example in your original question implied that dates are unique in your data - so answer actually addresses this scenario. with your new example  - this becomes quite a different question! So ideally - you should revert your original question; accept the answer and post new question :o)

Comment: That is very true - I will try to explain the issue more thoroughly from the get go in my the new SO question! I was trying to make the data as simple as possible to get the point across - clearly I failed and know that it’s on me. I am super thankful for any help and for all of your answers here on SO.