# How to get an array of user_id's being active at a specific point in time based on their latest event in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a problem where I'd like to get all user_id's in the "active" state for each day. An event is recorded only when the state changes for a user. The state for each user_id should be preserved until an "inactive" event is fired (see example data and outcome). Different users can have their state changed during the same day.

How do I do this? I have tried working with ARRAY_AGG and also grouping the two different events and using lag based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66357036/how-do-i-get-an-array-of-ids-having-a-specific-value-as-their-latest-value-at-a). I get stuck at the phase where I would then need to subtract the user_id's that get the inactive event from the array.

```
SELECT DATE("2019-11-11") as date, 1 as user_id, "inactive" as state UNION ALL 
SELECT DATE("2019-11-12"), 2, "active" UNION ALL   
SELECT DATE("2019-11-13"), 1, "active" UNION ALL 
SELECT DATE("2019-11-14"), 1, "inactive" UNION ALL
SELECT DATE("2019-11-14"), 3, "active" UNION ALL 
SELECT DATE("2019-11-15"), 2, "inactive"
```

Desired output:

```
date      | active_users

2019-11-11| []
2019-11-12| [2]
2019-11-13| [2,1]
2019-11-14| [2,3]
2019-11-15| [3]
```

Appreciate the all and any help I can get!

Comment: When user has their state changed multiple times within the same day - just having date is not enough - you need to have either timestamp or date time so proper order of states will be identifiable. Please consider and fix your question

Comment: I would also recommend presenting more sample data to cover different cases as I feel that your current example is still oversimplified and will potentially trigger follow ups anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to generate a series and aggregate. First, get the range of days for activity:

```
select t.*, date_add(next_inactive, interval -1 day)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when status = 'inactive' then date end) over (partition by user_id order by date desc) as next_inactive,
             max(date) over () as max_date
      from t 
     ) t
where state = 'active'
```

Then generate the dates and aggregate:

```
select day, array_agg(user_id)
from (select t.*, date_add(next_inactive, interval -1 day) s last_active_date
      from (select t.*,
                   min(case when status = 'inactive' then date end) over (partition by user_id order by date desc) as next_inactive,
                   max(date) over () as max_date
            from t 
           ) t
      where state = 'active'
     ) t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(date, coalesce(last_active_date, max_date), interval 1 day) day
group by day;
```